# Titanium 3.1.2.GA. I got an errror "hooks/tisdk3fixes.js:165" during build

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have an app which I develop on `Titanium Studio, build: 3.4.0.201409261227` and on `Titanium SDK 3.1.2.GA`

The app was developed well and has been on the market for almost 1 and a half year now.  Recently, the customer asked me to update it.

I tried to build it with `SDK` higher than `3.3.0.GA` but I got errors as the higher `SDK` uses themes plus one of the modules does not support higher titanium `SDKs`.

So what I did was install the old build of `Titanium studio` as above and using `CLI SDK` install, I install `Titanium SDK 3.1.2.GA.`  Installation had no problem

However, when I try to build the app and run it on the emulator or a device, Titanium gives me the following error;

---

```
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/hooks/tisdk3fixes.js:165
        var pd = data.result[1].options['project-dir'],
                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
    at cli.on.post (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/hooks/tisdk3fixes.js:165:27)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/lib/hook.js:242:13
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:689:13
    at iterate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:265:13)
    at async.forEachOfSeries.async.eachOfSeries (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:284:9)
    at _parallel (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:688:9)
    at Object.async.series (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:710:9)
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/lib/hook.js:232:11)
    at /Users/HezlyMohamed/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.2.GA/cli/commands/build.js:28:5
at /Users/HezlyMohamed/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.2.GA/node_modules/titanium-sdk/lib/titanium.js:116:3 
at Object.exports.execFile (child_process.js:712:9)
    at exports.exec (child_process.js:591:18)
    at async.series.cached (/Users/HezlyMohamed/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.2.GA/node_modules/node-appc/lib/android.js:86:4)
    at /Users/HezlyMohamed/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.2.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:486:21
    at /Users/HezlyMohamed/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.2.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:185:13
    at iterate (/Users/HezlyMohamed/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.2.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:108:13)
    at /Users/HezlyMohamed/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.2.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:119:25
    at /Users/HezlyMohamed/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.2.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:187:17
    at /Users/HezlyMohamed/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.2.GA/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:491:34
```

Is it related to my `NodeJS` installation? need HELP.  the funny thing is that for the other `Titanium SDK 3.3.0.GA` and `3.5.0.GA`, which i installed as well to test, the error did not appear showing the titanium installation was OK for building apps but I can't use them because of the module limitation.

Can anyone help me and give me some solution steps please.  And please don't tell me to upgrade to the new appcelerator platform.. it will not solve my problem as the app will not compile with high level Titanium SDKs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the Titanium SDK, at least you should have to upgrade build to titanium version 4.1.0 GA.
Now apple also require build to support ARMV 64 bit architecture, otherwise your build will not be accepted to App Store, this feature also you  will not get in 3.1.2 GA for this you need to upgrade sdk, so best option available to you is to upgrade the to titanium 4.1.0 GA or latest titanium sdks 5.2.2 GA.

3.1.2 sdk is completely outdated titanium sdk so please upgrade the sdk.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, Yes you are right.. I am developing on the latest platforms and SDK.. but  I need to use the 3.1.2.GA SDK  just to make small changes on an old app.  One of the module don't support newer SDKs for some reason and the original developer have disappeared.  I got the the installed correctly but I stumbled across the issue above.  Has anyone faced the same problem?  If  that is solved, then I can help the customer update his app, otherwise I have to redo them all over again.

Comment: There is no other option available other then upgrading the titanium SDK, earlier we also had got same issues so we upgraded the sdk and made build compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Titanium 3.1 is not supported anymore, neither is Titanium Studio. Try to use Titanium OSS CLI 3.1.4 (`[sudo] npm i -g titanium@3.1.4`) and NodeJS 0.10 and you might get it to work.